# How can the selection of a textarea be determined/manipulated in Safari from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, selection

I have some JavaScript code that does two things:

- retrieves the selected text from a text area
- adds a prefix and suffix to that selected text

The code currently uses the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the textarea to figure out where the selection starts/end, extracts the selection text and processes it, and then re-writes the value of the textarea with the prefix and suffix inserted in the right spots.

This implementation works fine in Firefox **but it does not work in Safari**. Apparently the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties do not exist in WebKit. (I suspect that the code also does not work in Google Chrome, which is also WebKit-based, though I have not tested this.)

How can I perform these two operations in Safari?

Comment: I use it in Chrome and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for 
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:Selection

also appears to work in Safari (not tested by me) (see: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Web-dev/2005/Nov/msg00114.html

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping for something a bit more explicit. eg: exactly how do I replace the selected text? Note also that I only want to do this if the selected text is in a textarea. If random text on the page is selected I'd like to give the user an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

See goog.dom.selection in Closure.